# Insert a picture into an imageview

Tags: java, android

In my app, I insert two pictures into two image-views and I use activity for result to fetch the photo from gallery.

```
 private void showFileChooser () {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
}

private void showFileChooser2 () {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.setType("image/*");
            intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2);

        }
    });
}


 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    rbitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 1000);//Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageViewUserImage.setImageBitmap(rbitmap);
                    imageViewUserImage.requestFocus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath2 = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath2);
                    rbitmap2 = getResizedBitmap(bitmap2, 1000);//Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageViewUserImage2.setImageBitmap(rbitmap2);
                    imageViewUserImage2.requestFocus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

The app is doing well but sometimes a weird thing happens.Sometimes once I click the desired photo in gallery, the app returns to the main activity and I find the previous loaded image in the other image-view is deleted.In other words, sometimes loading a picture in one of them deletes the loaded image in the other.
That glitch doesn't happen always, it sometimes happens and sometimes the app works well without any problem.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.The size of the images are kind of large so a "memory is out" error appears.To avoid such problem, I recycled each bitmap within its if case.

```
private void showFileChooser () {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
}

private void showFileChooser2 () {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.setType("image/*");
            intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2);

        }
    });
}


 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    rbitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 1000);//Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageViewUserImage.setImageBitmap(rbitmap);
                    bitmap.recycle;
                    imageViewUserImage.requestFocus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath2 = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath2);
                    rbitmap2 = getResizedBitmap(bitmap2, 1000);//Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageViewUserImage2.setImageBitmap(rbitmap2);
                    bitmap2.recycle;
                    imageViewUserImage2.requestFocus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a break point in the catch on the 'e.printStackTrace();' line.
Play with the app, and see the reason for failure.
Without any stack trace we can only guess the reason.